# Compiler Error CS0201

Tags: c#

This question might be a bit nitpicking but I really need to understand this.

I have the following Code:

```
string.Equals("0", "1"); //returns false, does compile
```

and

```
int i = 1;
i == 0; //should return false, does not compile
```

The second part throws the exception

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k626bk8b.aspx), at least an assignment (`=`), method call `()`, `new`, `--` or `++` operation must be called.

**Question**: Does that mean `==` isn't a method?

Comment: You can't use a comparison `i == 0;` as a single statement. The same would happen if you tried to declare a variable as the only statement of an if block e.g. `if(true){int i = 0}`

Comment: == is not a method indeed, it's an operator

Comment: `==` is an *operator*. It can be *backed* by a method for custom types but the compiler is free to compile specialized code when there are types it knows about involved.

Comment: If it doesn't compile then it's isn't returning anything.

Comment: @DarrenYoung thanks i've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  `==` isn't a method.  It's an operator.  And a comparison operator, by itself with nothing observing the result of the comparison, makes no sense.

You *can* do this:

```
i.Equals(0);
```

Because `.Equals()` is a method call, and as you demonstrated with `string.Equals()` you can call a method on a line by itself (even if you ignore the result of the method).

---

**Edit:** To clarify on something you've edited into the question:

```
i == 0; //should return false
```

An operator doesn't "return" a result, but it does *evaluate to* a result.  (A custom method backing/overloading an operator notwithstanding, but that method is being used under the hood by the framework to evaluate the result.)  However, operators can only be used in contexts where the language allows it.  In the case of a comparison operator, the compiler doesn't allow it to exist as a statement by itself.  (There's no need to allow it, so there's no need for the language/compiler/etc. teams to support it.)